# real time data aggregation - Dynamodb streams vs Kinesis data streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have the following use-case:

Users respond to a poll with a thumbs up/down vote. The poll will last for only a few seconds. Expecting around 30K users to respond to the poll in 10-15 seconds. The aggregated count should be displayed in real-time. Speed is more important than consistency of data.

**Approach#1**
Store data of each customer as a separate record in a Dynamodb table. Turn on streams for this table. Lambda can aggregate and store the count in a separate record. This record will be updated for each lambda invocation.

Pros: If batch size is 1, real time can be achieved.
Cons: For 30K users, 30K lambda invocations will be required. Updating the aggregated in the same record might lead to hot partition issue in Dynamodb.

**Approach#2**
Stream the data using Kinesis data streams. Batch process the data (for every 1 second) using a lambda. This lambda will aggregate the records and update a count record in Dynamodb.

Pros: Fewer lambda invocations. No hot partition issue in Dynamodb.
Cons: With batch processing, absolute real time cannot be achieved. Users can respond to the poll multiple times. UserId level data is not persisted.

Need suggestions on the above approaches or any other alternative approach to achieve real time aggregation for the above use-case